# How do you output to console from within angular code?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and having trouble figuring out how to test things in console with it. I am used to outputting variable values to the console as I code to check that the values are what I think they'll be. For example, if I want to get the length of an array I would just do `console.log(myArray.length)` inside of my code. If I put that inside of my controller function, nothing happens. And nothing happens if I put it inside of a function inside of my controller? I know I can inspect a particular element with $0 but that doesn't help in testing the code, I don't want to have to type the code into console to test aspects... Right now I am not using Angular in the context of the MEAN stack - I'm just using html, js, bootstrap and angular inside of MAMP; so, I'm not using node or a testing framework. Do I need to? And if so, can I use a testing framework without configuring the project environment with node/express? Thanks for your help.

```
angular.module('foil')

.controller('DonorListCtlr', function($scope, $http, $log, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){

    $scope.donors = []; 


    $http.get('api/list_donors.php').then(function(response){
        $scope.donors = response.data;
    });

    //create list of tabs
    $scope.tabs = [];

    $log.log('your stuff');

    $scope.gifts = [];  

    $scope.openTab = function(donor) {
        var newDonor = angular.copy(donor);
        $http.post('api/get_gifts.php', $httpParamSerializerJQLike({id: donor.id}), 
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response) {
            $scope.tabs.push({donor: newDonor, gifts: response.data});
        });

    };

    //add ability to close tab  
    $scope.closeTab = function($index) {
        $scope.tabs.splice($index, 1);
    };


    //submit form fields to process php to update donor details
    $scope.saveDonor = function(donor) {
        $http.post('api/process.php', 
        $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
            'donor_first': donor.donor_fname,
            'donor_last': donor.donor_lname, 
            id: donor.id 
            }), 
        {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}} ).then(function() {
            for(var i=0; i< $scope.donors.length; i++) {
                if($scope.donors[i].id === donor.id) {
                    $scope.donors[i] = donor;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: So you are trying to say that console.log() is not working inside the controller!!. Either I didn't get the context of the question properly or I am missing somthing. Could you just explain it again?

Comment: What browser are you using? You are looking at the console that opens if you press F12, right? Do you know how to set breakpoints there, to see if your JS code gets run?

Comment: Muhammed, yes; and stholzm, I'm using Chrome (v56) on a macbook.

Comment: The most common cause of `console.log` not working is that the app or controller didn't load properly. Try `angular.element($0).scope()` in the inspector console to see the scope variables in an app. If `undefined` then no app is running on the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have return like this in controller and included this controller in HTML page. Then without setting any environment you console.log should be working.
In controller write like:
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', function() {
        console.log("Hello");
    });
```

In HTML write like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="testApp">

    <head>
        <!--whatever files you need to add for css and bootstrap-->
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TestController">
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you console.log("Hello"); Should show the message in the console.
If this is not your answer then post your code with creating a plunker

Comment: Yes! This works as it should! :-) Only I don't understand why it doesn't in my own controller?

Comment: Does $scope encapsulate so much that you can't console log items within?

Comment: No you can print anything using console and wherever you want. You try printing console.log inside $http.get function after response or you try just above $http.get call

Comment: Thank you Vineet. I couldn't understand why console.log wouldn't work and now I see that it can. I needed to clear the browser cache/history and now it works in my controller as well as the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

try `$log.log('your stuff');`

Make sure you inject $log into controller

Add something like this

```
$scope.donors = []; 
$scope.GetDonors = function (){
$http.get('api/list_donors.php').then(function(response){
    $scope.donors = response.data;
});
};    
$log.log($scope.donors);
```

you have to invoke GetDonors from outside which will set your donors.

Comment: angular.module('foil')
.controller('DonorListCtlr', function($scope, $http, $log, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){

 $scope.donors = []; 
 $http.get('api/list_donors.php').then(function(response){
  $scope.donors = response.data;
 });
 
 //create list of tabs
 $scope.tabs = [];
 
 $log.log('your stuff');

 $scope.gifts = [];
...more

Comment: nor can I add all of the code for the controller - too many characters.

Comment: edit your post and add code. select code do a ctrl+k and then post it.

Comment: I edited the initial post to include the code. My aim right now is to have the console output the length and contents of $scope.tabs so I can 1. limit the number of open tabs and 2. prevent the same link from opening two or more identical tabs.

Comment: Krishna, Thank you. I cleared the cache and history and this approach worked too. Thank you also for the guidance in posting questions.